# Using laravel eloquent relation to retrieve all records except NULL

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to retrieve all the records which has not null using eloquent model.

e.g.

I have relation setup

Plate model

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Project');
}
```

project model

```
public function plate()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Plate');
}
```

How can I retrieve all the records which have value.

trying this `return  $p = \App\Models\Plate::with('project')->get();`

will return everything, even those who have `NULL`.

[image]

All I want is `plates` which have projects attached to.  I tried laravel documentation, but could't find anything. Is there also same approach for `many` relations

Comment: Don't forget you need plate_id column in your projects table to store the association

Comment: @daveyWavey Thanks for reply! I do not want to store anything for now. All I want is to retrieve all the `plates` which have `porjects` attached to it. and not `NULL`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use the `has` method to only retrieve plates that have a project.

```
\App\Models\Plate::with('project')->has('project')->get();
```

Docs on `has`: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations